# smoothing cylinder

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

Is there any way to smoothen cylinder's faces just like subdivision modifier does with sphere?

- Shade smooth - is not a solvation, just in case).
- Subdivision modifier itself disfigures cylinder.
- Subdivision operation in edit mode adds extra faces but doesn't change it's shape (doesn't smoothen it).
- Subdividing in edit mode + "Smooth" instrument does better, but it changes cylinder's dimensions.
- Increasing amount of vertices while adding cylinder - is a way, but
  what if i need some extra smooth after it's already added?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Subdivision modifier and Edge Crease

Subsurf disfigure the cylinder, until you tell him to maintain a sharp edge at the extremities.

Select the edge loops at the extremities, then press <kbd>Shift+E</kbd> to enter in Edge Crease mode. Drag your mouse until the edges are perfectly sharp (Edge Crease = 1.0).

[image]