# Modelling Technique Rounded Surface

Tags: modeling

I’m practising on this model, and I’d like where the blue curved line is to be more crisp. So when I add an additional loop where the yellow line indicates the loop cut, my mesh becomes from round to a more triangle projection. How can I keep the smooth curve, but make that dip where the blue line is more crisp without affecting that particular area?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Perhaps edge creases could help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/167867/78972

Comment: Yes, that worked perfect!

https://ibb.co/Y8zFXcr


Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You just want the flow of your holding edges to go in the right direction not to interfere with the outside curvature:

[image]

Often, you can avoid hand-work by Beveling with segments 2, profile 1, or to leave adjustments in play, you could use a Bevel modifier .. If so, you could look into controlling bevel-widths by edge Bevel Weight.

Even if you're not going to keep the Bevel modifier alive, (you're going to apply it,)  the modifier can still make selection more practical. It's often important to bevel crossing edges simultaneously. The result of beveling one edge, and then a crossing edge, is different. So accumulating the right selection to go off in one shot can be a pain. Assigning Bevel weights, applying the modifier, and then setting all the weights back to 0 can make that easier.

[image]

Comment: Hi Robin, great tip, thanks for your image work too!